# Select com php javascript ajax json

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

```
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.12.0/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
        <script  src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

   function run(){    

   var id = $("#id_Turma").val();
   console.log(id);


     $.ajax({
        url : "includes/disciplina.php/",
        type : "POST",
        data : { 
            id : id
             },
        success : function(JSON) {
            $("#idDiciplina").html("");
            console.log(JSON);



             $('#idDiciplina').append("<option value='' selected='selected'>Disciplinas</option>");

            for (var i = 0; i < JSON.length; i++) {
                $('#idDiciplina').append("<option value="+JSON[i][0]+">" + JSON[i][1] + "</option>");

            }

            }

    }); 

}
```

Vejam o código não consigo identificar porque  raios o não consigo capturar os valores do json pelo for.

```
<?php       

 //include('../seguranca.php');

 $id_turmar = $_POST['id'];
           $consulta = DB::getConn()->prepare("SELECT idDisciplina, Nome FROM `disciplina` WHERE Turma_idTurma = :Turma_idTurma;");
            $consulta->bindParam(':Turma_idTurma',  $id_turmar, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $consulta->execute();
            while ($assunto = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))  { 

             $assunto_post[] = array(
            'idDisciplina'  => $assunto['idDisciplina'],
            'Nome' => utf8_encode($assunto['Nome']),
        );  

            }
   echo(json_encode($assunto_post));
```

Comment: Qual o resultado de `console.log(JSON)`?

Comment: [{"idDisciplina":"13","Nome":"Matematica"},{"idDisciplina":"14","Nome":"Portugues"},{"idDisciplina":"15","Nome":"Geografia"}]

Comment: Então não deveria ser `JSON[i].idDisciplina` ao invés de `JSON[i][0]`?

Comment: Se eu coloco JSON[i][0] o resultado é [
cadastroQuestao.php:136 {
cadastroQuestao.php:136 "
cadastroQuestao.php:136 i
cadastroQuestao.php:136 d
cadastroQuestao.php:136 D
cadastroQuestao.php:136 i
cadastroQuestao.php:136 s
cadastroQuestao.php:136 c
cadastroQuestao.php:136 i
cadastroQuestao.php:136 p
cadastroQuestao.php:136 l
cadastroQuestao.php:136 i
ele coloca uma letra em cada linha e continua saltando.

Comment: Se eu coloco JSON[i].idDisciplina surge como resultado  136 undefined

Comment: Você colocando `"<option value="+JSON[i].idDisciplina+">" + JSON[i].Nome + "</option>"` não resolve o problema?

Answer (score 0):

Tenta usar for ... in:

```
for (j in JSON) {
   $('#idDiciplina').append(
      "<option value="+ JSON[j].idDisciplina +">" + JSON[j].Nome + "</option>"
   );
}
```

não lembro se precisa usar var -> `for(var j in JSON){`

Comment: Testei com e sem o Var.

Comment: A sua variavel JSON é um array ?

Comment: bom é para ser eu define isso, achei que era atribuído automaticamente.  como faço para defini-la como array?

Comment: Primeiro recomendo vc mudar a palavra JSON para outra, tipo data ou result, pois JSON é uma palavra reservado do javascript.
No seu console.log(JSON) deveria aparecer isso:
JSON Array(3)0: {idDisciplina: "13", Nome: "Matematica"}1: {idDisciplina: "14", Nome: "Portugue‌​s"}2: {idDisciplina: "15", Nome: "Geograf‌​ia"}length: 3__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: então eu coloco dada[] ou qualquer outro nome e o javascript o interpretara como sendo array.

Comment: Não. Na verdade eu quis dizer que JSON é o nome de uma variavel do javascript que manipula jsons, onde vc pode converter um json para string JSON.stringify(myObj) ou uma string para json JSON.parse(string).
Voce usando a palavra para pegar o retorno do ajax vc susbstitiu essa variavel.